# How to access the H264 stream from webcams that feature H264 hardware encoders?

Tags: encoding, directshow, video-capture, h.264

I'm developing a video capture application using DirectShow and I'd like to take advantage of the H264 hardware encoders present on some web-cams.

In particular I'm looking at two cameras: the Creative Connect HD VF0750 and the Logitech C920 which both claim to feature H264 hardware encoders.

Using GraphEdit, so far I've had mixed results. The Logitech C920 camera exposes an H264 stream as a Pin on the DirectShow WDM Capture filter but only on Windows 7. Trying the same on Windows 8 only shows output Pins for MJPEG and uncompressed YUV streams.

On the other hand, the Creative Connect HD VF0750 camera does not appear to expose an H264 Pin at all - even in Windows 7.

Yet, they both claim H264 encoders, and they claim that Skype can take advantage of the hardware encoders.

So the question is - what interface or API does Skype use to obtain the hardware encoded H264 stream from these cameras?  Since they're offered by different manufacturers it stands to reason that they use some common API and not just some obscure made-for-Skype custom interface.

I've used code like this to enumerate all pins and media types/sub types for each:

```cpp
IBaseFilterPtr f = getBaseFilterFromEnum();    // code omitted for brevity

IEnumPinsPtr pEnum;
f->EnumPins(&pEnum);
IPinPtr pin;
while (pEnum->Next(1, &pin, NULL) == S_OK)
{
    PIN_INFO PinInformation;
    pin->QueryPinInfo(&PinInformation);                 

    IKsPropertySetPtr pKsPropertySet = pin;
    if(pKsPropertySet)
    {
        GUID Category;
        DWORD nCategorySize;                

        if(SUCCEEDED(pKsPropertySet->Get(AMPROPSETID_Pin, AMPROPERTY_PIN_CATEGORY, NULL, 0, &Category, sizeof Category, &nCategorySize)))
        {
            // checks category type here

            IAMStreamConfigPtr pAmStreamConfig = pin;
            if(pAmStreamConfig)
            {
                int fmts, sccsz;
                pAmStreamConfig->GetNumberOfCapabilities(&fmts, &sccsz);
                BYTE* scc = new BYTE[sccsz];            

                for (int i = 0; i < fmts; i++)
                {
                    AM_MEDIA_TYPE* mt;
                    pAmStreamConfig->GetStreamCaps(i, &mt, scc);
                    if (mt)
                    {
                        if (mt->pbFormat)
                        {
                            // query here based on mt->formattype

                            //  and based on mt->subtype
                            if(mt->subtype == MEDIASUBTYPE_H264)
                            {
                                // has H264
                            }else if(mt->subtype == MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24)
                            {
                                // has RGB
                            }else if(mt->subtype == MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2)
                            {
                                // has YUY2
                            }else if(mt->subtype == MEDIASUBTYPE_MJPG)
                            {
                                // has MJPEG
                            }else
                            {
                                // has some other sub-type
                                //   not getting this on either of my cams
                            }
                            // free mem here
                        }
                        // more free mem here
                    }
                }
                delete[] scc;
            }else{                  
                // Error Getting Formats - this happens for the Video Terminal Pins
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

This is output I'm getting for the two cameras on Windows 7:

```
Live! Cam Connect HD VF0750
   Capture (CAPTURE):  
       18 Formats: RGB; YUY2; MJPEG; (VIDEO_INFO; )
   Video Camera Terminal (UNKNOWN):  
       Error Getting Formats
   Still (STILL):  
       3 Formats: RGB; (VIDEO_INFO; )
HD Pro Webcam C920
   Capture (CAPTURE):  
       106 Formats: H264; YUY2; MJPEG; (VIDEO_INFO; VIDEO_INFO2; )
   Video Camera Terminal (UNKNOWN):
       Error Getting Formats
```

On Windows 8, the output is different. Neither of them come up with H264 sub-types (despite both claiming to support H264 hardware-encoded stream).

At least in Win7 the Logitech camera provides the H264 pin as expected.

Comment: Basically you do it right, another format discovery option you might be interested in is enumerating media types using `IPin::EnumMediaTypes` - you might see H.264 there.

Comment: Also FYI, [`DirectShowCaptureCapabilities-Win32.exe`](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Toolbox/) is a quick way to enumerate media types using `IAMStreamConfig` (the way you already do it).

Comment: @RomanR. thanks for chiming in. Any ideas why on Winodws 8 the same camera does not offer the H264 media type?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that cameras behave differently in different versions of Windows (or, different versions/builds of drivers at all). Another question is can Skype really leverage H.264 hardware encoding with them or not? If yes, maybe it's possible to check it's filter graph and see how it does it exactly.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not sure how to do that (check the filter graph of another application). But I also think there may be some other things it does to enable the H264 output using UVC extension units. I found out that in the case of Logitech it is the drivers that disable (my guess is just hide) the H264 media type on the output pin.

Comment: You can install my [DirectShowSpy](http://alax.info/blog/777) and then have Skype's fitler graph details printed into "C:\ProgramData\DirectShowSpy.log". You only need to `regsvr32` the spy thing and then have Skype restarted, this should be sufficient for the things to start rolling. Then uninstall with `regsvr32 /u` to cleanly remove the spy (or, you might want to keep using it for DirectShow development).

Comment: Thanks - I'll try and see if I it uncovers anything valuable

Comment: What program gives you the output you quoted in your question?

Comment: amn@ it is the code snippet in the question

Answer (score 3):

Over time I received a few submissions from users for video capture capabilities of Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 camera in different systems. The data is [here](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities/Data/). Availability of hardware H.264 video requires specific (most recent?) version of driver, and behavior is different across operating system versions. While in Windows 7 H264 media type is available on the capture pin the usual way, in newer OSes there is a separate additional Capture pin with H264 media types. Apparently, applications capturing H.264 are assumed to be aware of this new layout and connect pins/capture appropriately.

The same applies to Logitech Webcam C930e camera (Windows 7 - [no H.264 at all](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities/Data/Logitech%20Webcam%20C930e.md), Windows 8.1 - [H.264 on second capture pin](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities/Data/Logitech%20Webcam%20C930e,%20Blackmagic%20WDM%20Capture,%20Decklink%20Video%20Capture.md)).

The data on the secondary capture pin has standard [`MEDIASUBTYPE_H264`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757808) formatting:

[image]

Comment: Hi Roman - thanks for answer this. I was wondering if you'd be available for a chat some time as I might have some information to complement your work..

Comment: On my Windows 7 x86-64. building a graph from the C920 media source with Graph Studio Next x86-64 gives me a *dedicated* H.264 capture pin. This contradicts your statement "... in Windows 7 H264 media type is available on the capture pin the usual way". I just wanted to mention this.

Comment: @amn: it's driver dependent, it could be same pin with original driver, then as a separate pin with a newer one. I don't think I saw dedicated H.264 pin for C920 in Windows 7, but it does not mean it's impossible. If you post your data with [my tool](http://alax.info/blog/1531), I will add that to my [database](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities/Data/).

Comment: Submitted. I thought the same thing, which is why I wrote the comment -- hinting perhaps at the fact that it may not be merely platform dependent but may also the driver, for instance. Anyway, you have driver version information in the payload from my submission, from what I saw from the text.

Comment: @amn: I don't have driver versions in earlier submissions so I cannot compare, but FYI I checked a few of earlier submissions and yes H264 is on a dedicated pin. That is, it also applies to C920 in Windows 7. As far as I remember though this design was introduced with Microsoft's support for UVC cameras, so I suppose Logitech later adopted similar pattern. Either way, it is important that H.264 can be available from additional pin, not necessarily from the first/main Capture pin.

Comment: @RomanR. Do you know how can I set I frame interval(GOP) for H264 streams?

Comment: @Alam: [`CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317889)?

Comment: @RomanR.Yes something like that. I want to use Logitech's inbuilt encoder. I am not clear how to set GOP. I can set width and height  using VIDEOINFOHEADER property. But I cannot find ICodec property

Comment: @RomanR. I am using "Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920" it does not have `ICodecAPI` property

Comment: @Alam: Right, C920's support of H.264 is a sort of limited. It is not a [H.264 UVC 1.5 device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj218765), and hence the H.264 capabilities. C930e has the `ICodecAPI`.